# wxPython Listctrl Counter

Tags: python, wxpython, listctrl

How do you detect duplicate values in a listctrl? I want to know if I enter values and if it is a duplicate, the counter would add 1 and would not add another row in the list. Hope someone can help. I'm still a super noob. :D

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "List Control Tutorial")

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.index = 0
        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel)

        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(-1,100),
                         style=wx.LC_REPORT
                         |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                         )
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Line')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Number')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Count', width=125)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Add Line")
        btn2 = wx.Button(panel, label="Get Column 1")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_line)
        btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.getColumn)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.text_ctrl,0,wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND,5)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn2, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def add_line(self, event):
        line = "Line %s" % self.index
        self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, line)
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, self.text_ctrl.GetValue())
        self.index += 1

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def getColumn(self, event):
        """"""
        count = self.list_ctrl.GetItemCount()
        for row in range(count):
            item = self.list_ctrl.GetItem(itemId=row, col=1)
            print item.GetText()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple options, but the easier option is simply to keep track of what you put in the `ListCtrl`:

```
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "List Control Tutorial")

        self.listitems = set()
        # or [] in cases where the items aren't hashable

        ....

    def add_line(self, event):
        textval = self.text_ctrl.GetValue()
        if textval not in self.listitems:
            line = "Line %s" % self.index
            self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, line)
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, self.text_ctrl.GetValue())
            self.index += 1
            self.listitems.add(textval)
```

etc.